# Monitor Calibration Software

Tags: display, hdmi, lcd, calibration

When I connect my laptop to the TV using HDMI cable, the edges of the screen are not visible (I lose about 20 px in each direction). My LCD TV does not support calibration position/scale.

Is there any monitor calibration software  for Windows 7 that allows adjusting horizontal/vertical position and scale?

Comment: Check your resolution and or or color depth and refresh rate. It might just fix itself if you get it right.

Comment: It's an overscan issue, look at your display driver configuration like ATI Catalyst, nVidia forceware etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a laptop with an Intel HD graphics card on-board. There are no options to change scan rate or refresh rate. I have tried changing color depth too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut-off problem was perfectly solved by using the remote control of my Toshiba LCD TV to change aspect ratio mode for the HDMI connection to "PC".